# Can we use "Call read" in file karateconfig.js

Tags: cucumber, karate

Trying to pass basic auth file in karate config.js
below lines are working.

```
        }
        karate.configure('headers', {'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='});

    return config;
```

}

Instead of above code is it possible to add these below lines into karate config.js?

```
    * header Authorization = call read('../../basic-auth.js') { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in 2 steps:

```
var token = karate.call('auth.js', { username: '', password: '' });
karate.configure('headers', { Authorization: token });
```

Read this if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-vs-read